# Merge files using Hadd

Tags: merge, pyroot

I am attempting to merge three ntuples (just an example but there are more) stored in a directory that are labeled as the following:

```
[1] mc16a_SUSY.root
[2] mc16d_SUSY.root
[3] mc16e_SUSY.root
[4] ......
```

To do this I am using the command hadd (hadd outputfile inputfiles..)

```
os.system(hadd -f Combined_SUSY_SAMPLES.root mc16*SUSY*.root)
```

For the output file I want to combine all files with mc16 and SUSY in the file name

But I receive the error:

```
hadd Target file: Combined_SUSY_SAMPLES.root

hadd compression setting for all output: 1

hadd Source file 1: mc16*SUSY*.root

Error in <TFile::TFile>: file mc16*SUSY*.root does not exist

Error in <TFileMerger::AddFile>: cannot open file mc16*SUSY*.root

hadd exiting due to error in mc16*SUSY*.root
```

It states that there aren't any files with `mc16*SUSY*.root` but these files do exist. Any solutions? Thanks for the help in advance.

I use the "*" because there are to many files to list them individually.

Comment: (Just noticed this was from 9 months ago, sorry.) Hi, you can try directly from the terminal, you can do first `$ ls mc16*SUSY*.root` to see if your files are there, then, `$ hadd -f Combined_SUSY_SAMPLES.root mc16*SUSY*.root`. On the other hand, can you try to adding quotation marks in `os.system('hadd -f Combined_SUSY_SAMPLES.root mc16*SUSY*.root')`, `os.system()` takes as argument a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to respond here, but could it be that you don't have the full path to the files? Some databases will send you the file names with certain commands, but not the absolute locations.  It could be that you need to append the folder to the beginning of the filename.